# How to change TableList UILabel backGroundColor when we tapped on UIbutoon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I am very new in iOS and I have created one tablelist on my Viewcontroller and here on my tablelist row I have added one UIlabel programatically, ok that's fine.

And I have added one UIbutton programatically on my "self.view".

Here my main requirement is when I click that button, I want to change UIlabel background color which was added on my tablelist row.

For this I have tried the code bellow, but UIlabel backgroudcolor is not changing.

Please help me.

### my code:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){

UILabel *label;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController {

    UITableView *tableView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self tablelistCreation];
}

//UItableView createtion

-(void)tablelistCreation{

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, self.420) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

//Delegate methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 300, 50)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    return cell;

}

//UIbutton createtion

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button .backgroundColor = [UIColor orangecolor];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 440, 30, 30);
 [self.view addSubview:button];

//button action

-(void)Method:(id)sender{

  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redcolor];

}
```

Comment: Actually where do you want to set the button? I mean Do you want to set the button inside the tableViewList or outside of the tableviewlist?

Comment: out side of the  tableList and when we tapped on it UIlabel which was added on TableList row BackGroundColor need to change

Comment: Krish Please check my answer

Comment: If my answer is useful,tick and up vote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was not clear if you want to change the label color on all cell or just some.

Anyway this color change must be made cellForRowAtIndexPath which is where the update / creation of the cell is made.

You can create a variable to inform if you want the color change or not and it check this on cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
@implementation ViewController {
    UITableView *tableView;
    bool changeColor;
}

-(void)Method:(id)sender{
  changeColor != changeColor;
[tableview reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.text = [yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UILabel label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 300, 50)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    }


   if (changeColor){ 
      label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redcolor];
   }else{
      label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   }


return cell;
}
```

if you want change especific labels, you can create a nsarray to control what cell will be change

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ViewController (){

    UILabel *label;
    NSMutableArray *lableArray;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController {

    UITableView *tableView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self tablelistCreation];

    lableArray=@[].mutableCopy;
}

//UItableView createtion

-(void)tablelistCreation{

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, self.420) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

//Delegate methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 300, 50)];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

        [lableArray addObject:label];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//    
//    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 300, 50)];
//    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    return cell;

}

//UIbutton createtion

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button .backgroundColor = [UIColor orangecolor];
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 440, 30, 30);
[self.view addSubview:button];

//button action

-(void)Method:(id)sender{

    [lableArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setBackground:) withObject:[UIColor redColor]];
//    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redcolor];

}
```

cell is Reusable so creation should put in  cell == nil condition,at every run into the condition will creation a new UILabel ,if you want change all of them ,you should put them in a collection ,such as NSMutableArray...

Answer (score 0):

## import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()
{

  UILabel *label;
  BOOL isTouchButton;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController {

    UITableView *tableView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 
    //UIbutton createtion

   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   button .backgroundColor = [UIColor orangecolor];
   button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 440, 30, 30);
   [self.view addSubview:button];

    [self tablelistCreation];
}

//UItableView createtion

-(void)tablelistCreation{

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, self.420) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

//Delegate methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 300, 50)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    label.tag = indexPath.row;

    if(!isTouchButton)
    {
      cell.labelUserName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    else{
      cell.labelUserName.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    return cell;

}


//button action

-(void)Method:(id)sender
{
  if(!isTouchButton)
  {
    [tablelistCreation reloadData];
    isTouchButton = YES;
  }
  else{
    [tablelistCreation reloadData];
    isTouchButton = NO;
  }

}
```

Comment: i have attached related screen through this link please see once  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05NQoG9RAmwdGFYUVNEdWFXRG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry as i had some work i could not answer you correctly.Now i will help you.